# Injecting selectors with prototype

Tags: javascript

I am comparing at two way of injecting jQuery selectors, I have even created a jsPerf (http://jsperf.com/prototype-vs-function-selector).

Say I have the following:

```
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

I can do this:

```
function Class1() {}

Class1.prototype.displayName = function(selector) {
  $(selector).hide();
}

var f = new Class1();
f.displayName($(".wrapper"));
```

or I can do this:

```
var displayName = function(selector) {
  $(selector).hide();
}

displayName($(".wrapper"));
```

the both achieve the same result.

My question is:

for this kind of static things where you want to hide, remove class and similar stuff is the prototype approach an overkill? (Since I will only inject the selector once)

Comment: http://jsperf.com/prototype-vs-function-selector/2

Comment: Don't use classes as method bags. Classes solve a very specific problem, namely modeling your data as objects. If you don't have model anything, don't use classes.